# Html button colour change on click

Tags: javascript, html

hopefully this is a pretty easy one, I am building a web app using flask and python. On the front end of the app I am trying to get it to change the colour of the button pressed and revert any previous colour changes to other buttons so only the most recently selected button is a different colour.

The buttons are populated from an sql database so all use the same html line in a for loop. Below is the code I have currently:

Colour change script:

```
<script>
var count = 0;
function setColor(btn, color) {
    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (count == 0) {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "red"
        count = 0;
    }
    else {
        count = 1;
    }
}
```

Button code:

```
 {% for item in categorydata %}
  <tr>
    <button id="{{item[0]}}" formtarget="Items" name="ItemCategory" value={{item[0]}} onClick="setColor('{{item[0]}}', '#101010')" style="color:black;height:50px;width:150px" >{{item[0]}}</button>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Use css, the :`focus` psuedo-class

Comment: by click on the button, you add `backgroundColor` for the current button but not clear color for all buttons. You can add loop which takes all buttons and clear background

Answer (score 2):

for this kind of problem you don't need to use JS.
you have to do is use **css :focus psuedo-class**

for ex:

```
.btn:focus {
 background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So one way of doing this would be to add a class "modified" to the button pressed and remove class "modified" from the previously pressed button

## CSS

```
modified {
    background-color: black;
}
```

## Javascript

```
function calledOnClick(id){
    previousPressedButton =  document.getElementsByClassName("modified")[0]; //there should only be one item, check before hand if items exist ofcourse.
    previousPressedButton.classList.remove("modified")
    pressedButton = document.getElementById(id)
    pressedButton.classList.add("modified")
}
```

## HTML

```
<button id=1 onclick="calledOnClick(this.id)"></button>
```